# Seamonkey cannot create multiple email accounts

Tags: email, seamonkey

I configured Seamonkey to read my mail and news, and all works fine. Currently I have Seamonkey checking one mailbox and two news servers.

Now I'd like to be able to have Seamonkey check a second mailbox, but a strange glitch prevents me to do that.

When I select *Create a new account*, the Account Wizard window opens and asks me for my Identity settings: name and email address. After clicking on Next, it asks me for my NNTP server. I don't want to create a newsgroup account, I want to create a mail account.

Moreover, if I enter a dummy value for the NNTP server, and finish the process, it does not create a new account -- it destroys one of the News accounts I previously set up!

This happens even if I don't finish creating the account; if I enter some dummy value (e.g. the Name) in the Identity window, then click on *Next*, then on the next screen I click on *Cancel* to abort the account creation, I find that the dummy value has overwritten the correct value in one of the existing accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears [it's a known Seamonkey bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521861).

One of the comments in the bugreport suggests fixing by hand the prefs in `about:config`:

> I think the problem is the leftover valid setting for the news server. Usually you can see the pref for a short time when you create an account manually. (...)
>
> When you cancel the subscription (...) you end up with a mail.server.serverX.valid boolean pref set to false. This seems to confuse the heck out of the account wizard. The simple solution seems just to delete the pref. The not so simple solution would be to make sure that every mail.server.serverX has such a valid pref regardless of it's setting. This seems to work too.

On my part, I managed to solve the problem by deleting both news accounts. This made the New Account Wizard restore its normal behavior, so I was finally able to create a second mail account.